# Layout folder for New Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-layout, nexus-7

One of our user complaint that app does not look good on New Nexus 7(1200*1900 with 323PPI resolution). I am not getting which layout folder I have to create to give support this new device.

Comment: I will give a try with layout-large-xhdpi

Answer (score 3):

You should use layout-sw600dp because large might include 5 inch devices like Dell Streak also - From the Android guidelines.

The new Nexus 7 uses xhdpi resources but for app icon, it uses xxhdpi. That's what I've observed in my app on my Nexus 7.

Answer (score 1):

Should fall into xhdpi bucket.

```
ldpi : ~120dpi
mdpi : ~160dpi
hdpi : ~240dpi
xhdpi : ~320dpi
```

Answer (score 0):

The new Nexus 7 is of 320dpi. So it falls on the `large xhdpi` bucket.
So you can specify layout as `layout-large-xhdpi`.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 7 picks the resources from tvdpi folder . Please try that like layout-large-tvdpi, drawable-large-tvdpi.

Sorry , I was talking about old Nexus 7 , new Nexus 7 picks up from `large-xhdpi`.

Comment: No, that's the original nexus 7. The OP is asking about the new Nexus 7.